# node ODBC install for NWjs on Windows fails

Tags: node.js, odbc, node-webkit, nwjs, node-odbc

I'm using nodejs and node webkit for a windows app (node-webkit is now NWjs).

I installed the `node-odbc` module and used the included tests to see if it works. Testing the database connection worked fine via the command line ("node aTestFile.js"), but the moment I try to call it from within index.html inside node-webkit, I receive the following error:

```
Uncaught node.js Error 

Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. 
c:\Users\SomeUser\Documents\Development\accessingDB\node_modules\odbc\build\Release\odbc_bindings.node
    at Error (native)
```

And if I try to add the file as the node-main in the package.json, nothing happens.

I need a little help. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

as noted in the docs for NWjs (previously node-webkit), I found the following solution worked on Windows 10 when using an LTS release:

1. preliminary install for Windows node_modules, first install Nodejs from nodejs.org and then: `npm i -g windows-build-tools node-gyp` and be sure to enable showing file extensions in explorer (so the next step has file extension '.cc')
2. replace file `win_delay_load_hook.cc` at path `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\src` from GitHub source `https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/blob/nw18/tools/win_delay_load_hook.cc`
3. now proceed as usual `npm install`

for non-LTS releases or more help refer to the official docs:
http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Advanced/Use%20Native%20Node%20Modules/